# How can I catch an exception from Publish-Module?

Tags: powershell

I am using Publish-Module and one of the modules had a bad psd1 file. PowerShell threw an exception as expected. The call to Publish-Module is inside a try block but the error handling code in the catch block never ran. It appears that this error is not being caught.

There is another error that happens in this same PowerShell code where the module I am publishing already exists in the repository. When that error occurs the code in the catch block runs and processes the exception. Is there something different about the first exception that would cause the catch block to be bypassed?

### Code snippet:

```
    try {

        Publish-Module -Path .\$moduleName -Repository MyRepo -NuGetApiKey ghehdue

        "Module $moduleName published."

    }
    catch {

        if ($_.Exception.Message -ilike "*cannot be published as the current version*is already available in the repository*") {

            "The latest version of module $moduleName already exists in the repository."

        }
        else {
            $exitCode += 1
            Write-Error $_

        }
    }
}
```

### Error that is not caught

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Test-ModuleManifest : The module manifest 'J:\Builds\
Jenkins\PROJECT_2456764.0\Applications\ALM\PSModules\MyCompany.Build\MyCompany.B
uild.psd1' could not be processed because it is not a valid Windows PowerShell 
restricted language file. Remove the elements that are not permitted by the 
restricted language:
At J:\Builds\Jenkins\PROJECT_2456764.0\Applications\ALM\PSModules\MyCompany.Bui
ld\MyCompany.Build.psd1:13 char:9
+ GUID = 'ccaa548f-8194-4cfa-a659-260f6ddc556b'
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Unexpected token 'ccaa548f-8194-4cfa-a659-260f6ddc556b'
# Author of this module
Author = 'MyCompany'
# Company or vendor of this module
CompanyName = 'MyCompany' in expression or statement.
At J:\Builds\Jenkins\PROJECT_2456764.0\Applications\ALM\PSModules\MyCompany.Bui
ld\MyCompany.Build.psd1:13 char:9
+ GUID = 'ccaa548f-8194-4cfa-a659-260f6ddc556b'
+         ~
The hash literal was incomplete.
At J:\Builds\Jenkins\PROJECT_2456764.0\Applications\ALM\PSModules\MyCompany.Bui
ld\MyCompany.Build.psd1:19 char:25
+ CompanyName = 'MyCompany, Inc.'
+                         ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
At J:\Builds\Jenkins\PROJECT_2456764.0\Applications\ALM\PSModules\MyCompany.Bui
ld\MyCompany.Build.psd1:118 char:1
+ }
+ ~
Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
At C:\Program Files 
(x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:989 char:27
+ ...   $module = Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Test-ModuleManifest -Path $mani ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (J:\Builds\Jenki...Quip.Bui 
   ld.psd1:String) [Test-ModuleManifest], MissingMemberException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_InvalidManifest,Microsoft.PowerShell.Com 
   mands.TestModuleManifestCommand
```

### Error that is caught

```
publish-module : The module 'DqCryptography' with version '1.0.2' cannot be published as the current version '1.0.2' is already available in the repository 'http://usas26:8624/nuget/PROJECTPowerShell/'.
At line:1 char:1
+ publish-module -Path DqCryptography  -Repository PROJECTPowerShell - ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Publish-Module], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ModuleVersionIsAlreadyAvailableInTheGallery,Publish-Module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the try block add an error action to the Publish-Module

```
Publish-Module -Path .\$moduleName -Repository MyRepo -NuGetApiKey ghehdue -ErrorAction Stop
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!